# How can I verify WordPress nonce from the following code?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nonce

Please check the blockquote code. It don't working on header. I think this condition can't take the values when it's came from the body to header. But, what's the solution for it?

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Manage Days
*/


if ( isset($_GET['remove_date']) && isset($_GET['_wpnonce']) ) {
    $delete_date = $_GET['remove_date'];
    $delete_nonce = $_GET['_wpnonce'];

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $delete_nonce, 'holiday_nonce' ) ) {
        die( 'Failed security check' );
    } else {
        $delete_holiday = $wpdb->delete( 
        $wpdb->prefix . 'ab_holidays',
            [ 'staff_id' => $staff_id, 'date' => $delete_date ],
            [ '%d', '%s' ] );
    }

}

get_header(); ?>

    <?php
        $disable_dates = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ab_holidays WHERE staff_id = '$staff_id'");

        foreach ( $disable_dates as $disable_date ) {
            $originalDate = $disable_date->date;
            $newDate = date("F j, Y", strtotime($originalDate));

            $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'holiday_nonce' . $originalDate );
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '?remove_date=' . $originalDate . '&_wpnonce=' . $nonce . '" class="delete-holiday"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>' . $newDate . '<br />';
        }
    ?>

<?php
get_footer();
```

> if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $delete_nonce, 'holiday_nonce' ) ) { ....
>   } else { ..... }

Comment: You create the nonce 'holiday_nonce' plus the date but you are checking the nonce against only "holiday_nonce' without the date, so It will always return false,

remove the "$originalDate" part from wp_create_nonce()

Comment: Great. But, If I remove `$originalDate` then all url are showing same **nonce**. Suppose I have 10 url all url showing same nonce. which is another problem.

Comment: I don't think It's a problem, The nonce is  to make sure that the current user who did the request, The important is to match the same nonce for the current user

Comment: Your are right. But, WordPress suggest separate **nonce** for separate url for security purpose. For example, WordPress admin posts. Do you have any solution for this problem? TIA